# terminal won't launch after install python 3.5

Tags: python3

After I installed **Python 3.5** and ran the commands below, my terminal and many other programs won't launch any more.

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo rm python3
sudo ln -s python3.5 python3
```

How can I restore the default Python version again to fix these problems?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Step 1: Opening a terminal

You said that you could not open a terminal any more. That is because the standard terminal emulator in Ubuntu is `gnome-terminal`, which can't run without a working `python3`, as that's one of its dependencies:

```
$ apt-cache depends gnome-terminal | grep python
 Depends: python3
 Depends: python3-gi
```

However, there are alternatives:

1. **Use another terminal emulator:**

   You can simply use another terminal emulator than `gnome-terminal`, for example **`xterm`** which should also be installed by default. Search it in the dash's application lens (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) or just run `xterm` from the HUD (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>).

   A new terminal window will open from where you can undo your previous operations. It's (in my opinion) less comfortable than the default `gnome-terminal`, but surely does its job without depending on any Python components:

   ```
   $  LANG=C apt-cache depends xterm | grep python
   $
   ```
2. **Use a TTY terminal:**

   Instead of using a terminal emulator (terminal window in a graphical environment) you can also temporarily switch to a real terminal (console only, no graphics) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (or any <kbd>F [n]</kbd> key with n in the range of 1 to 6).

   You switch back to the graphical surface (usually TTY7) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (or another <kbd>F [n]</kbd> key with n in the range of 7 to 12, depending on your user sessions).

   In the TTY, you will have to log in by typing your username and password again first. Then it works like a normal terminal. Don't forget to log out of the TTY session again with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or the command `exit` when you're done.

---

### Step 2: Restoring the original `python3`

Whatever method you used to get a terminal, the following reparation step is the same.

You have to restore the original `/usr/bin/python3` file, which was actually a symlink to `python3.4` (or absolute path `/usr/bin/python3.4`). This is done by the following simple command:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: You can download Visual Studio Code and use it's built-in terminal - I had this same problem and I fixed it using the Visual Studio Code terminal via running the various commands through that terminal to fix the Python stuff https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads

Comment: It should be noted that the graphical session is typically on TTY1 and 2 for newer versions of Ubuntu, instead of TTY7.

Answer (score 9):

You can't replace Python 3.4 with 3.5 on Ubuntu, because many (system) applications rely on it. This includes the symlink `python3`.

Given that you have not removed `python3.4`, restore the original symlink with

```
 cd /usr/bin
 sudo rm python3
 sudo ln -s python3.4 python3
```

Call Python3.5 directly with `python3.5`

Comment: You can download Visual Studio Code and use it's built-in terminal - I had this same problem and I fixed it using the Visual Studio Code terminal via running the various commands through that terminal to fix the Python stuff https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and the following worked for me:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Selecting `1` genreated:

```
* 1            /usr/bin/python3.5   1         manual mode
```

Comment: You can download Visual Studio Code and use it's built-in terminal - I had this same problem and I fixed it using the Visual Studio Code terminal via running the various commands through that terminal to fix the Python stuff https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads

Answer (score 0):

Terminals and other applications cannot be launched because the latest version of python3 on your ubuntu does not symlink to python3.
You can overcome this by doing a symlink in the following way:

Check the version of python3 in `/usr/bin`:

```
ls /usr/bin | grep python
```

Selecting the latest version of the python3(`python3.5`) symlink becomes `python3`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Choose your version of python3 (`python3.5`) with number. if successful, the result is

```
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3.5 to provide /usr/bin/python3 (python3) in manual mode
```

Open your default terminal or restart

---

if there is an error in point 3, such as:

```
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternatives /usr/bin/python3.7 because the python3 link group is broken
```

Please repeat point 3 and choose another version of `python3`.