# Failed to launch "Terminal"

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-gnome

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 but I cannot open the terminal. when i want to open the terminal i face a notification that is given below . please help me 
I cannot install any other apps

[image]

Comment: What terminal application are you trying to open? What notification appears? Are you able to open another terminal emulator program?

Comment: Did you try ctrl+alt+t?

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/780626/terminal-wont-lauch-ubuntu-16-04/978471

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by installing xterm from software, and running `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal`. This gave me an error I hadn't seen before, which was that my python installation was not as expected. I fixed the python installation and everything works again.

The python issue was that I was trying to use a python version manager, but gnome-terminal was looking for the binary python3 in `/usr/bin`. I had disabled that binary by renaming it to `old_python3`. I renamed it again to `python3` and everything worked.

Comment: Perhaps complete your answer by adding information about how you fixed the python installation in the event others face the same issue?

Comment: @Graham updated.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem after installing `python 3.7.0`. 


@steel, Could you explain a bit more -- **`A binary I had moved`**. Which binary had you moved from which location to which location and also which binary?

Comment: @Johir I added the details to the answer, but it was specifically looking for the `python3` binary.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that terminal is missing from your system for some reason. You can check that by checking out

```
/bin/gnome-terminal
```

You can install it using ubuntu software center. Open the software center and type "terminal" and then install it.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution for me was to follow the steps from the link below but changing the python version to the 3.6 in my case.

https://askubuntu.com/a/978471/1118361

Answer (score -2):

- Try to update your locale
- Try to change your environment variables or reset them to their default values.
- Or just restarting your PC sometimes help

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What do you mean by "update your locale"? How would that help? How does changing or resetting environment variables help? Which variable should be reset?