# cannot open gnome-terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I do not know why my terminal is not working. I clicked terminal icon, and it didn't launch. There is no error message. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> is not working, also. I can launch <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

I tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686177/terminal-wont-launch-after-install-python-3-5). But, it didn't solve the problem.

After running the `gnome-terminal` command from an XTerm, I get this error message:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal: 
        /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You mean /usr/bin (beginning slash)?

Comment: Ah yes! I tried the solution, but it didn't solve the problem @ubfan1

Comment: Can you please give a little more details about the system. Which version Ubuntu are you running, and have you tried rebooting?

Comment: It is possible you have a phantom display with the terminal on it. Check the output of `ps auxx | grep term` and see if there are any terminals open and owned by your user. Do you have multiple displays, and or is this on a laptop or a desktop with multiple graphics cards? I have seen phantom LVDS displays before.

Comment: What about other terminal emulators, like xterm? Can you start that one?

Comment: I am using 16.04 on my laptop.  I tried rebooting. My computer is Asus X550VC, I think it has only one graphic card. Here is the output of `ps auxx | grep term` : `merve 3083 0.5 0.1 81484 11372 ? S 22:36 0:00 xterm -class UX Term -title uxterm -u8
merve 3113 0.0 0.0 15628 972 pts/1 S+ 0:00 grep --color=au to term` @ben-NabiyDerush

Comment: Yes I can use xterm.  @ByteCommander

Comment: And what happens if you run the command `gnome-terminal` from an xterm?

Comment: After run the `gnome-terminal` command: `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`  @ByteCommander

Comment: And what did you do to your Python 3 installation?

Comment: Looks like you found the culprit (at least why it is not working) - now to find why your python3 is missing....

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution? If so, can you **[edit]** this post to provide the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python*`?