# Ubuntu 18.04 terminal not opening

Tags: command-line, python, xterm

I have just installed python 3.7 for a project I need. I think it wasn't necessary. Already had python2.7 and python3.6 but I wanted to be sure. So after the installation, the terminal stopped opening. Also used `xterm` command through alt + F2, like some other solutions suggested but it was not found...I thought it was default installed.

Any ideas???

Comment: Did you remove python2.7? Or change the symbolic link of python?

Comment: no i did not remove it. changed the link when asked like the tutorial showed. that was my mistake i guess...

Comment: Ubuntu uses python for a lot of purposes. I guess it can not find it now. Almost exactly the same thing happened to me. Additionaly i had deleted 2.7. If in any way, you can revert the python link back to python2.7, it may return back to normal.

Comment: Can't find a way. Guess i will have to do a format...

Comment: The seniors here could help you better but I guess you can do it by booting with a Live CD.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [terminal won't launch after install python 3.5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686177/terminal-wont-launch-after-install-python-3-5)